# How to prove that the first passage time is finite?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be iid random variables with $$P(X_j = 2)= 1/3, P(X_j = 1/2) =2/3.$$ Let $M_0 = 1$ and for $n \geq 1, M_n = X_1X_2 \cdots X_n$.

Let T be the first time that $M_n = 4$. Is it true that $P(T<\infty)=1$? How to show that? My ultimate goal is to find the probability that $M_n$ ever reaches $4$ by optional stopping theorem.

Comment: It is not true. $\log(M_n)$ is a sum of independent random variables with negative mean, so there is a nonzero probability that $M_n\to 0$ without first hitting $4.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen It is nonzero, but it is not $1$ right? So, is there still some poibility of reaching $4$?

Comment: Yes. A simple lower bound is there is at least a 1/9 probability of reaching 4, since you reach it on the first two tries with that probability. Note that the probability of ever reaching 4 is exactly the same is that probability of ever reaching 2 in a simple biased random walk with $1/3$ probability of moving right and $2/3$ of moving left.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You mean upper bound of reaching 4? How do we show that $\exists N$ in $\mathbb N$ s.t. $\forall \omega, T(\omega) < N$?

Comment: 1)I mean a lower bound on the probability of reaching $4$ is $1/9$... you have at least a $1/9$ probability of eventually reaching $4$. 2) You can't show that because it is false.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Isn't 1/9 the largest probability we can get? If we do not have $2$ on the first two tries, then we need to use more steps to reach $4$, which decreases our probability or reaching $4$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asymmetric simple random walk.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752207/asymmetric-simple-random-walk)

Comment: Other ways to do it will have smaller probabilities than 1/9, yes. But these add to the total probability of hitting 4, making it larger than 1/9.

Comment: @user10354138 So the probability of $M_n$ ever reaching $4$ is $1/9$?

Comment: No.  You obviously get $\frac14$ as the hitting probability.

Comment: @user10354138 Umm.. could you write an answer to explain that?

Comment: Do you understand why it is the same as the probability of ever hitting $2$ in a random walk starting from $0$ with $p=1/3$? If so, I’d suggest finding a textbook solution to that problem and reading it.